# image expands during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following script is making an image on my webpage display very large while the page is loading, then resize to the correct proportions. Looks very strange while the page is loading. Any idea why and what I can change to fix it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){var container=jQuery('.cmsms_slider_599c9017c6dfd');containerWidth=container.width(),firstPost=container.find('article'),postMinWidth=Number(firstPost.css('minWidth').replace('px','')),postThreeColumns=(postMinWidth*4)-1;postTwoColumns=(postMinWidth*3)-1;postOneColumns=(postMinWidth*2)-1;jQuery('.cmsms_slider_599c9017c6dfd').owlCarousel({items:4,itemsDesktop:false,itemsDesktopSmall:[postThreeColumns,3],itemsTablet:[postTwoColumns,2],itemsMobile:[postOneColumns,1],transitionStyle:false,rewindNav:true,slideSpeed:200,paginationSpeed:800,rewindSpeed:1000,autoPlay:false,stopOnHover:true,autoHeight:true,addClassActive:true,responsiveBaseWidth:'.cmsms_slider_599c9017c6dfd',pagination:false,navigation:true,navigationText:["<span class=\"cmsms_prev_arrow\"><span></span></span>","<span class=\"cmsms_next_arrow\"><span></span></span>"]});});</script>
```

Comment: Where is your image? Is it somewere inside `container`? Is the image _(with it's real resolution)_ big or does it feat inside your browser's window? In which element in the DOM is your image wrapped in?

Comment: Yes, the image is the one being referred to in firstPost I believe. It's a four column row of images, and the first image is the problem. I made the image super small just to test that theory - it blows up no matter what it's true resolution is. I'm honestly a JavaScript idiot, just trying to help out a friend and fix the issue.

Comment: I can't find the source of the problem either in the code or intuitively, could you send us some screenshots when the image is big and another one after the page loads completely?

Comment: I appreciate you looking into it Daniel. You can see the two images here......https://s3.amazonaws.com/rescue-bucket/blowup.png    https://s3.amazonaws.com/rescue-bucket/normal.png

Comment: Gonna check this out in a moment!